# JsonNaming and NotNull Validation conflict

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, jackson

I think Validations and JsonNaming annotations are in conflict.

hello everybody.
I try to validate a DTO object properties (specially @NotNull validation), while have set `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)` for DTO.
when I send request and try to get request body as DTO, Bad Request Exception will be thrown.
if I remove @NotNull annotation everything will be OK.
but DTO should be validated.

my DTO is:

```java
@Data
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OTPRequestDTO {

    @NotNull
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

and it's my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LoginController {
    private final LoginService loginService;

    @GetMapping("/otp")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> getOtp(@Valid OTPRequestDTO otpRequestDTO) {
        loginService.sendOTP(otpRequestDTO);
        return 
                 ResponseEntity
                    .ok(ResponseDTO
                                .builder()
                                .status(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                                .message("OTP sent     successfully")
                                .build()
                      );
    }
}
```

Do the two libraries and annotations conflicts?

Comment: Looks good I think, might just be the name mapping with Jackson. If your JSON body definitely contains phone_number then this should work fine, but I think what's happening is it may not and you get null assigned to phoneNumber resulting in `@Valid` complaining. Or possibly JSON body contains phone_number but is null or type is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

let look your request data
you chose SnakeCaseStrategy.class
the request file SNAKE_CASE like snake_case

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).